# High memory utilization in the Linux server

Tags: linux, websphere

JVMS heap usage and GC is working as expected but we are still observing more than 90% MEM usage in Linux top command. 
Please advise.

Comment: You paid for memory for your server. Do you not want it to be used?

Comment: High memory  (more than 90%) utilization is a major concerning factor which does have performance impact.

Comment: As long as there's no SWAP memory in use and the amount of memory is not steadily increasing, this is not a problem as @EEAA said. If you had only 10% of memory usage, then your hardware would be oversized. If you were using 100% of real memory and some % of the SWAP, then it'd be undersized. What you need to do is to monitor the application memory usage (both real and swap), the load average and so on.

Comment: @user7011135 Citation needed.

Comment: @user7011135 Did you read the duplicate question and its answers? You are making a lot of incorrect assumptions about memory usage and its effects on performance.